# Haskell cabal install: missing C library iw

Tags: haskell, xmonad, cabal-install

I'm running Fedora 19 x64, and
I'm trying to install xmobar via cabal install.  After installing a bunch of dependencies, I'm stuck at

```
cabal: Missing dependency on a foreign library:
* Missing C library: iw
```

I can't find anything about this iw library and I'm a bit lost at how to continue.

I've got all of the standard c libs installed, as far as I can tell.

```
sudo yum install glibc-common glibc glibc-devel glibc-headers glibc-utils glibc-devel      glib2-devel gcc-c++ gcc
Loaded plugins: auto-update-debuginfo, langpacks, refresh-packagekit
Package glibc-common-2.17-18.fc19.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package glibc-2.17-18.fc19.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package glibc-devel-2.17-18.fc19.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package glibc-headers-2.17-18.fc19.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package glibc-utils-2.17-18.fc19.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package glibc-devel-2.17-18.fc19.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package glib2-devel-2.36.3-3.fc19.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package gcc-c++-4.8.1-1.fc19.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package gcc-4.8.1-1.fc19.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

Comment: A google search for `libiw` returns tons of results. Find the appropriate one and install it (and its headers).

Comment: Thanks Carl.  In case I run into this type of error again: are all C libraries basically named lib + whatever the title is?

Comment: Also, you may need the "dev" version of the library. It might be called libiw-dev.

Comment: @Wieschie That's the convention. I'm not sure it's always the pattern, but it usually is.

Comment: Someone dare to add this as an answer and grab some sweet reputation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Libraries are packaged differently by your OS.  For fedora, if you're missing library `A`, you often will find packages named `libA` and `libA-devel`.  Luckily, you don't need to guess - instead just ask yum what packages has some file of interest.  Below, I asked about the shared object file `libiw.so`.

```
yum whatprovides *libiw.so*
...
1:wireless-tools-devel-29-9.1.fc19.x86_64 : Development headers for the
                                      : wireless-tools package
Repo        : fedora
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/lib64/libiw.so



1:wireless-tools-29-9.1.fc19.x86_64 : Wireless ethernet configuration tools
Repo        : installed
Matched from:
Provides    : libiw.so.29()(64bit)
Filename    : /lib64/libiw.so.29
```

I'm surprised Fedora would install without these packages, but if that's the case then obtaining the packages is just a `yum install` command away.

Answer (score 3):

Under Ubuntu the same workaround:

<sup>**`cabal: Missing dependency on a foreign library:
    * Missing C library: iw`**</sup>

was resolved though I thought that it can be also two libraries for *C language build tools*:

1. **liwc** : Tools for manipulating C source code
2. **iwyu** : Analyze #includes in C and C++ source files

after these additions & **libiw-dev** library new **xmobar** was compiled.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone trying to install xmobar through cabal on arch,

the missing package that includes `iw` is called `wireless_tools.`

You can install that with

```
pacman -S wireless_tools
```